# User goes back to authorization URI when authenticated with Spring Security OAuth2 Login

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, facebook-oauth

I'm using Spring Security OAuth2 Login to authenticated users with Facebook account. Everything works well. However, I have an issue, when a user logs in successfully and clicks back button and opens Facebook authorization URI for a second time (https://www.facebook.com/v2.8/dialog/oauth). It again redirects to callback URL /login/oauth2/code/facebook with a new code, but this time authentication fails. Oauth2 Login failure handler gets called and redirects to default failure URL. Here is the exception

```
org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2AuthenticationException: [authorization_request_not_found]
```

Therefore the issue is that the second authentication was not initiated by security oauth2 code and it doesn't expect this second callback. Any idea how this can be solved? Is it possible to ignore this second callback? Ideally the second authentication should also be successful.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this problem was to open the authorization URL (/oauth2/authorization/facebook) in a pop-up window with JavaScript. The pop-up window would respond to the parent window with JavaScript postMessage.